# Docker error PHP : Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a legacy project : PHP 5.3 - apache 2.2 - mysql 5.5

I'm trying to create lamp php 5.3 but I can't connect my app to mysql

I'm using docker, but my php error is :
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

My code is here :
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8097c6e781fc6cbfd25079eb2544914c

Thanks for your help/tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect using compose are you making sure you connection string host is named `db`?

Comment: docker-compose exec db mysql -h localhost -u root -proot -D my_database is working

Comment: right, so does my answer solve your issue?

Comment: no because is on my app I can't connect

Comment: Oh yes sorry ! why I can use db ! Oh thanks !